# Triggering an action of a different page using NavigatorIOS Buttons

Tags: react-native

I'm making an app with two Buttons in the Navigator in the Homepage. I have also used React Native Side Menu. (https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-side-menu)

From the left button of the NavigatorIOS, I want to trigger the toggle() method of the Side Menu. How am I to accomplish this?

```
<NavigatorIOS
    style={styles.navigationContainer}
    ref="nav"
    initialRoute={{
    title: "Home",
    component: Home,
    ref:'home',
    rightButtonTitle: 'Items',
    leftButtonTitle: 'Menu',
    onLeftButtonPress: () => {
        //menuActions.toggle(); HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    },
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
    this.refs.nav.navigator.push({
        title: "Items",
        component: Items
    });
    }
}} />
```

The code and the elements for the Sidemenu is in the Home file. How to access this from this code, which is in the index.ios.js?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not enough to make a conclusion. First of all, I need to see, how you compose your components. `menuActions` are available only for children components thru the context. Based on this code fragment I can't see how you make do it.

My suggestions:
- Check if you `NavigatorIOS` component is a children of your SideMenu component
- If you don't want to use `NavigatorIOS` as a children of a SideMenu, you may need something like a global store (you can use redux, for example) which will reflect a state of the SideMenu. Subscribing to this store from the right place (in any children of SideMenu), you'll be able to trigger `menuActions` from the place it'll be accessible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will update as soon as I get the fix done. :)